# KeyError: '...' keeps coming back

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

I keep getting the error and can't find where the problem lies. I'm trying so I can choose wether I want the attack the creature or both printed and what type the creature is: 'easy', 'medium' or 'hard', I want to store that into a variable.

```
creature = {'easy': ['chicken', 'slime', 'rat'],
            'medium': ['wolf', 'cow', 'fox'],
            'hard': ['baby dragon', 'demon', 'lesser demi god']
            }

attack = {
    'easy': ['pecks you', 'spits juice at', 'scratches'],
    'medium': ['bites', 'charges at', 'bites'],
    'hard': ['spits sparks of fire at', 'rends', 'smashes']
    }

creature_easy = ['chicken', 'slime', 'rat']

cre = random.choice(creature_easy)
linked = dict(zip(creature[cre], attack[cre]))
cre_type = linked[0]
cre = random.choice(dict(creature))

print(linked[cre])

KeyError: 'rat'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `cre` is "chicken", "slime", or "rat".  But the `creature` and `attack` dictionaries have keys "easy", "medium" and "hard".

Comment: is value from `creature_easy` present as key in `creature` dictionary ?

Comment: @JohnGordon So how do I look at the the actual creatures behind "easy", "medium", "hard"?

Comment: You don't need `creature_easy`, you already have `creature['easy']`

Comment: @mozway oh, okay. But how do I pick a random out of the dictionaries?

Comment: `random.choice(creature["easy"])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want something like:

```
chosen_level = 'easy'
game_data = dict(zip(creature[chosen_level], attack[chosen_level]))

import random
cre = random.choice(list(game_data))
att = game_data[cre]

print(cre, att)
```

Output: `rat scratches`